# Search positions of elements in array using two lists

Tags: r, arrays, list

I have an array like this:

```
arr1<-array(1:5,dim=c(3,4,2))
```

And two lists like these:

```
li1<-list(1,2)
 
li2<-list(list(c(2,3)),list(c(1,2)))
```

#length(li1)==length(li2)

I want to check in the first (according to first element of li1) matrix of the array were I can find '1' in the rows 2 and 3 (according to first element of li2). I want also to check in the second matrix of the array (according to second element of li1) were I can find '1' in the rows 1 and 2 (according to second element of li2). And so on (if I had more elements in li1 and li2). The position of element '1' should be the corresponding column were the element can be found.
I can (almost) do that individually for each element of the lists.

```
f1 <- function(x) {which(arr1[x, , li1[[1]]] == 1)}
result <- lapply(li2[[1]], f1)
```

But I would like to do the same to n elements of li1 and li2, using an 'apply()' function. I'm struggling with that and trying different 'apply' combinations.

The result should be something like this:

```
> result
[[1]]
[1] 4 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 0
```

Comment: OK. Maybe the first list is not necessary. I would like to check the first element of li2 in the first matrix of the array, the second element of li2 in the second matrix of the array,... and so on, in the same way as above, i.e. in which positions (columns) can I find a certain item (say '1') in the rows indicated by the element of li2.

Comment: Is the question too difficult, too stupid or too specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my own intricate, primitive and unpolished solution:

```
df1<-t(data.frame(li2))

f1 <- function(x,y) {which(arr1[x, ,y] == 1)}

for (i in 1:2){
print(mapply(f1,df1[i,],i))
}
```